# How to collapse a tree to a fixed size in a balanced way

Tags: c#, tree

I'm building a web app that shows employee hierarchy in a company. A user can select any employee and a network size , and I need to display the reporting hierarchy for that employee/manager capped to the size. For ex: If an employee has 1000 members under him (direct reports and indirect reports) and if user wants to see a network of size 100 for this user, then I need to collapse the sub trees or not expand under him, so that overall nodes seen in the UI <=100.

This is what I got so far.

```
public void CollapseTree(Employee employee, int maxSize)
    {
        int size = 0;
        Queue<Employee> queue = new Queue<Employee>();
        queue.Enqueue(employee);
        employee.isVisited = true;
        size++;

        while (queue.Count > 0)
        {
            // Dequeue the employee
            Employee emp = queue.Dequeue();

            foreach (Employee report in emp.Directs)
            {
                // Check if we already visited this node
                if (!report.isVisited)
                {
                    queue.Enqueue(report);
                    report.isVisited = true;
                    size++;

                    // If we reached maximum size, then exit
                    if (size == maxSize)
                    {
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public HashSet<Employee> Directs { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int TotalDirects { get; set; }

        public int TotalReports { get; set; }

        public bool isVisited { get; set; }

        public Employee(string name)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Directs = new HashSet<Employee>();
        }
    }
}
```

What I have done is add a bool isVisited property to the nodes and then traverse the tree in BFS marking them as visited till I reach the max size. This doesn't create balance trees bcoz if for ex: we want a max network size of 10, and an employee E1 has 3 directs D1, D2 and D3. D1, D2 and D3 in turn have 20 reports each, then we expand D1, D2, D3 in first level and then go on to expand D1 and stop after we see 6 of D1's reports. This doesn't work.

I want to expand an employee only if we can expand all his directs w/o reaching the max network limit, else leave his/her subtree as collapsed.

How can I do this?

Comment: You don't need isVisited since you don't have any loops.  This is a left/right branch problem.  Once you have an accurate count of children all  you need to do is count the number of children to determine if a branch is expanded or not expanded.  A Node is expanded if the count of children is less than X.

Comment: Yes, if total of children.  If you have a binary tree then it is children/2.  You may want to keep a left child count and a right child count.